# Trying to apply PHP date format

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to apply a certain date format from MySql. The column field type is 'date' and is formatted in MySQL as an example 2015-03-16, and those fields without dates are *NULL*.

When I apply the following code, fields with dates are displayed correctly - 03/16/2015.

However, all the NULL fields in MySQL are displayed in the webpage with 31/12/69. Any idea what I can do?

```
if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT Vessel_Name, Builder, Built, Listing_Price, Date_Listed, LOA, Price_Original, Price_Previous, Amt_Reduced, Amt_Pct FROM boats")) {
    echo "Cannot parse query";
}
elseif(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
    echo "No records found";
}
else {
    echo "<table id=\"boatstable\" class=\"bordered\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
    echo "<thead>\n<tr>";
    echo "<th>Vessel_Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Builder</th>";
    echo "<th>Built</th>";
    echo "<th>Listing Price</th>";
    echo "<th>Date Listed</th>";
    echo "<th>LOA</th>";
    echo "<th>Original Price</th>";
    echo "<th>Previous Price</th>";
    echo "<th>Amt Reduced</th>";
    echo "<th>Amt Pct</th>";
    echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        echo "<tr><td>$row[Vessel_Name]</td><td>$row[Builder]</td><td>$row[Built]</td><td>$row[Listing_Price]</td><td>".date("m/d/y", strtotime($row['Date_Listed']))."</td><td>$row[LOA]</td><td>$row[Price_Reduced]</td><td>$row[Price_Previous]</td><td>$row[Amt_Reduced]</td><td>$row[Amt_Pct]</td></tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table><br />\n";
```

Comment: Why not just fix your display logic to handle `NULL`s correctly?

Comment: `null` is not a date

Comment: Do you want to fix that data after it has been selected or not select the rows with a NULL date?

Comment: Being new to MySQL, I am doing a display of the entire table with sortable headers. So it doesn't matter if there is a date in the Date_Listed column or not. I just want the date formatted from the MySql format of 2015-03-16 to 03/16/15. But if I have NULL in some cells, it displays 31/12/69 from those cells. If I remove the NULLs like this: UPDATE boats SET Date_Listed = ' ' WHERE Date_Listed IS NULL;, I get 00-00-00 displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Well you will have to identify the missing dates and put something else out instead, like so

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $fixed_date = $row['Date_Listed'] == 'NULL' 
                  ? 'n/a' 
                  : date("m/d/y", strtotime($row['Date_Listed']));
    echo "<tr>
            <td>$row[Vessel_Name]</td>
            <td>$row[Builder]</td>
            <td>$row[Built]</td>
            <td>$row[Listing_Price]</td>
            <td>". $fixed_date ."</td>
            <td>$row[LOA]</td>
            <td>$row[Price_Reduced]</td>
            <td>$row[Price_Previous]</td>
            <td>$row[Amt_Reduced]</td>
            <td>$row[Amt_Pct]</td>
        </tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly. But, if I have NULL, null is not a 0, so it can't be == from what I've read. Further, removing NULL, replaces all cells with 0000-00-00 in the Date_Listed column.

Comment: **NOTE** The last line of my answer. I said you may have to do some checking on what is actually returned when the date column is null and alter that test accordingly. So change it to `$row['Date_Listed'] == '0000-00-00'`

Comment: I did a quick test and it returns `'NULL'` So I chnaged my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, sorry, overlooked that. I understood all except the ? 'n/a'. I replaced with the following code and now get a blank page.      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $fixed_date = $row['Date_Listed'] == '0000-00-00' 
                   ? 'n/a'
                   : date("m/d/y", strtotime($row['Date_Listed']))
                   
        echo "<tr>
              <td>$row[Vessel_Name]</td>
              <td>$row[Builder]</td>
              <td>$row[Built]</td>
              <td>$row[Listing_Price]</td>
              <td>". $fixed_date ."</td> ...

Comment: make sure your php.ini is set to error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors= 1

i smell a hidden syntax error... like a missing semicolon ; but for the love of god, upgrade your PHP, and convert to MySQLi or PDO ( http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers )

Comment: @hanshenrik Well spotted, Dan, I missed the `;` from the end of the `$fixed_date = $row['Date_Listed'] == 'NULL' 
                  ? 'n/a' 
                  : date("m/d/y", strtotime($row['Date_Listed']));` line. I just dont understand these people that develop PHP with error reporting turned off. MADNESS!

Comment: Thanks Hans and Riggs! May still have questions along this line, but I want to research what you've given me...